# "unable to get local issuer certificate" in chef when using knife bootstrap with windows domain auth

Tags: chef, knife

I have a working installation of open source chef and am trying to add domain authentication to bootstrap Windows servers.

I've created the HTTPS listener as described in the [`knife windows` documentation.](https://docs.getchef.com/plugin_knife_windows.html#domain-authentication) I used the domain certificate for this node for the hex value.

When I try to run the following command:

```
knife bootstrap windows winrm #myip# -r 'role[#myrole#]' -x #MYDOMAIN#\\#myuser# -P '#mypass#' -p 5986 -VV
```

I get the following error:

```
Waiting for remote response before bootstrap.
DEBUG: Adding #myip#
DEBUG: :session => :init
DEBUG: :relay_to_servers => echo . & echo Response received.
DEBUG: :relayed => #myip#
DEBUG: #myip# => :run_command
at depth 1 - 20: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Since the domain certificate that I used for the hex value was a Rackspace issued certificate, I figured that perhaps it was not registered as trusted on the chef server or chef workstation. I've added the certificates to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` and ran `sudo update-ca-certificates` on both the chef server and workstation. I've also added the certificates in `.pem` format to `/opt/chef-server/embedded/ssl/certs` and `/etc/chef/trusted_certs` on the chef server and '/opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs` on the chef workstation.

Either my assessment of the issue was incorrect or I haven't reconfigured the certs correctly - either way, I'm lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Chef support, I needed to use port 5985 for both the listener and the chef bootstrap command making the command:

```
knife bootstrap windows winrm #myip# -r 'role[#myrole#]' -x #MYDOMAIN#\\#myuser# -P '#mypass#' -p 5985
```

Then I needed to install the new (pre-release) gem of `winrm-s` via:

```
gem install winrm-s --pre
gem uninstall winrm-s --version '= 0.2.0'
```

Then I needed to install the newest pre-release of `knife-windows` via [opscode github](https://github.com/opscode/knife-windows/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md).

Once all of that was complete I was able to bootstrap Windows servers from any Windows Chef workstation via domain authentication.